# Image Caching from http sources

Tags: xamarin.ios, xamarin.android, windows-phone, mvvmcross

I've read in a post from December 1st 2012 at Slodge bloch that File and DownloadCache plugins could be used for downloading and caching images from http sources. I think that's what I need in the app I'm trying to develop with MvvmCross (great framework, congratulations!!).

My app, first connects to a remote server to download some basic configs. One of these configs points to an url to get the app icon. To save bandwith, I'd like app caches the icon the first time it gets it until the url changes.

I performed some search with no much success and I'd like somone pointing me to a good demo on how to cache images from http sources and then binding these image to UI Image controls (Droid, iOS and WP)

Thaks

Answer (score 2):

Showing images on wp, winrt, xamarin.android and xamarin.touch from http is shown in these two N+1 videos:

- Kittens - N=2 - https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=e-ZKgO8fTw4
- Books - N=6 - https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=He6QvnLsPUA

Comment: Thanks Stuart, I'm not sure that's what I need. In these examples, File and DownloadCache plugins are only used with Droid and iOS app. I'm not sure if images are cached only during a "session" (so, every time app starts images are download from server). So my questions: Are images cached permanently (they are not downloaded again each time app starts)? How can I implement caching in Windows Phone and Windows Store app?

Comment: Sorry - I've answered your question "somone pointing me to a good demo on how to cache images from http sources and then binding these image to UI Image controls" - if that's not enough - if you need some custom business logic, then I think that's when you need to start coding :)

Answer (score 0):

I've faced the same issue recently and finally solved it. It was pretty easy, you just need to make sure that you added and initialized Cirrious.MvvmCross.Plugins.Json plugin in your project.

I created a similar question that it's solved already https://stackoverflow.com/a/17891681/1309164